# How to get the process name from server layer using PID

Tags: kernel, minix

I would like to be able to use the name of the process in `servers/sched/schedule.c` however `schedproc` structure doesn't contain the name variable. I thought about using `endpoint_lookup()` function to get the pointer to the `proc` structure but since it is defined in `kernel/proc.c` I wasn't sure if I could call it within `schedule.c` (from user space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In user space, you could use `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` to get the process's name, like

```
$cat /proc/$$/cmdline
```

`bash`